# How to remove a column of lines if it had a word

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, sed

I want to remove a a column in the line if the search key word exists within that column.

My input will be multi line input, some thing like and column delimiter is `:`

```
:I want to remove a : column in the line : if the search key word exists within : that column
:I will : be using : word as : the key word
:colon will : be used : as the : delimiter
```

and search keyword is `word`

My output should be

```
:I want to remove a : column in the line : that column:
:I will : be using :
:colon will : be used : as the : delimiter
```

Comment: your input lines do not end with `:` compared to previous version.. this effectively becomes a new question.. consider adding `:` to this version as well and ask a new question if you are not able to modify solutions

Comment: also mention if you need to remove all columns matching the search keyword or only first match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample input:

```
echo $x
:I want to remove a : column in the line : if the search key word exists within : that column:
```

`awk` solution:

```
 echo $x |awk -v RS=":" -v ORS=:  '!/word/'
:I want to remove a : column in the line : that column:
```

Explanation:

Use `RS` as ":" ,will make `awk` to consider each record is separated by ":".  Then print that record which does not contains the keyword `word` and then keep output records separated by ":".

Comment: this worked well and most suitable for my requirement. Thanks for help.

Comment: I tried it with multiple line input and I see whenever the search key word is in the last column, next line gets appended to the modified line. Is there any way to remain the next lines in newlines.

Comment: @VijeshKk it would be good idea to modify your question to include multiple line input file and expected output...

Comment: I agree with Sundeep, need sample input to modify our commands.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
:I want to remove a : column in the line : if the search key word exists within : that column:

$ sed 's/:[^:]*word[^:]*//' ip.txt
:I want to remove a : column in the line : that column:
```

- `:[^:]*` means `:` followed by zero or more non`:` characters
- `word` string to match
- `[^:]*` zero or more non`:` characters
- since replacement is empty, the matched string is effectively deleted
- Note that this will remove only first such match

Answer (score 2):

**Perl solution:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data=':I want to remove a : column in the line : if the search key word exists within : that column:';

my @cols = split(/:/,$data);

foreach my $cols(@cols) {
    if($cols ne "" && $cols !~ /word/) { #search keyword
        print ":",$cols #print other than search key word
    }
}
print ":\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl Code:

```
my $data="
:I want to remove a : column in the line : if the search key word exists within : that column
:I will : be using : word as : the key word
:colon will : be used : as the : delimiter";

print $data,"\n";

$data=~s/:[^:]*word[^:]*//mgi;

print $data,"\n";
```